Why doesn't $\iiint\limits_\Omega (y^2+z^2)dv$ equal $\int_0^5 2x\pi\cdot 2x\,dx$, rotating the curve $y^2=2x$ around the x-axis and the plane $x=5$?
Why doesn't $\iiint\limits_\Omega (y^2+z^2)dv$ equal $\int_0^5 2x\pi\cdot 2x\,dx$ when $\Omega$ is the closed area surrounded by the curved surface formed by rotating the curve $y^2=2x$ around the x-axis on the xOy plane and the plane $x=5$?
My solution to the problem is as follows：
Project the graph onto the yOz plane,
\begin{align*}
&\int_0^5 \pi y^2 (y^2+z^2)\,dx \\
= &\int_0^5 \pi 2x (y^2+z^2)\,dx \\
= &\int_0^5 \pi 2x 2x\,dx \\
= &\frac{500}{3}\pi
\end{align*}
But the right answer is $\frac{250}{3}\pi$. Where was I wrong?

The right answer is indeed $\frac{250}{3}\pi$. I'm going to demonstrate why is that and then discuss why your approach isn't what you usually want to do.
So, the shape we're given is actually a parabaloid. It would be easier to change the coordinates and use cylindrical ones as follows:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{>{\displaystyle}l@{}}
x=x \\
y=\rho \cos{\theta} \\
z=\rho \sin{\theta}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
where $x \in [0;\,5]$, $\theta \in [0;\,2\pi]$, and $\rho \in [0;\,\sqrt{2x}]$ by the construction of the constraining surface.
The Jacobian of the change is as always:
$$ J =
\left|
\begin{array}{ccc}
x_{x} & x_{\rho} & x_{\theta} \\
y_{x} & y_{\rho} & y_{\theta} \\
z_{x} & z_{\rho} & z_{\theta}
\end{array}
\right| 
=
\left|
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos{\theta} & -\rho\sin{\theta} \\
0 & \sin{\theta} &  \rho\cos{\theta}
\end{array}
\right| 
= \rho
$$
Hence the integral becomes:
$$
\iiint_{\Omega} (y^2+z^2)d\omega = \int_{0}^{5}\,dx \int_{0}^{2\pi}\,d\theta \int_{0}^{\sqrt{2x}}\,\rho^2 \, \rho d\rho.$$
This integral is the easiest to calculate, but I'll leave a few notes for the curious reader:
$$
\int_{0}^{5}\,dx \int_{0}^{2\pi}\,d\theta \int_{0}^{\sqrt{2x}}\,\rho^2 \, \rho d\rho = 2\pi \int_{0}^{5}\,dx \frac{\rho^4}{4}\Bigg|_0^{\sqrt{2x}}=
\frac{\pi}{2} \int_{0}^{5} 4x^2\,dx = \frac{2\pi}{3}\cdot x^3\Bigg|_{0}^{5} = \frac{250}{3}\pi
$$

What I think your mistake is reckless projection onto $yOz$. When you do so, you don't account for the fact that the volume "density", $y^2+z^2$ here, depends on $x$ in a non-linear way. What you have done, basically, or assumed to do, is smushed the parabaloid into the circle in the plane $x=0$. But throught $x \in [0; \,5]$ the value of $y^2+z^2 \neq const$, hence, the "circle" doesn't have a uniform density after the projection.
I could also suggest using standard Cartesian coordinates with proper integration boundaries to see where you've gone wrong.

Why did you say $y^2+z^2\neq const$? I think $y^2+z^2=2x$.

Because when you integrate over a volume, it's $y^2 + z^2 \le 2x$.
